# How we can pass response output of an API to another API as a variable by using JSON Extractor in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

How we can pass response output of an API to another API as a variable by using JSON Extractor in JMeter?

The answer of above questions with my personal problem.

Comment: [object Object]    Here, I am passing ' user' as variable but it does not read it value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the **full response** into a JMeter Variable for later re-use - go for the [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) and specify the desired variable name there.

In case you need a partial response, i.e. a specific attribute value - go for [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) or [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) and put the relevant query and/or transformation function there

Demo:

[image]